# Laravel Migration Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::integar()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTasksTable extends Migration

{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.

     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
             $table->integar('user_id')->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('food');
            $table->string('quantity');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tasks');
    }
}
```

Comment: Guessing here that the method is actually called *integer*...!?

Comment: this question should win some kind of award :-p

Answer (score 17):

You wrongly written `integer` spelling, write this `integer` instead `integar`

Here is my working sample code, see the integer line, I hope that might help you

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('app_type_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('app_type_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('status',1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you see a: "*Call to undefined method*" error it usually means you have misspelled something. I had something similar drive me crazy and I had just missed an arrow when chaining methods:

[image: Error location]

Just take a look here, it even says which line you need to check:
[image: Error message]
Pay attention to what the command line is telling you, those hints are more obvious than I'd care to admit!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder open `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` 
add the following code then run `php artisan migrate` in console.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; 

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder open app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php add the following code then run php artisan migrate in console

```
namespace App\Providers;
```

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
* Bootstrap any application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function boot()
{
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
```

}

Even If you are not able to migrate the Database after the changing stuff in code than try to change the Number on this function **defaultStringLength(191)**.
change to 99,199 or 191;

Comment: Not blaming you for the poor question, but try to explain why and how your solution works. Also, fix spelling mistakes and grammar.

Comment: Thanks for Feedback.
I hope you query is now clear. @MatiasChara